# Adapter to use a Doulton water filter on a Pfister faucet

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet

I live in the USA. The water in my unit is very bad, so I bought a [Countertop Filter from Doulton](http://doultonusa.com/HTML%20pages/cp100uc.htm), one of the highest-reviewed ceramic filters out there that uses a standard 22mm female thread.

Unfortunately for me, the faucet in the kitchen is a [Pfister Portland](https://www.pfisterfaucets.com/kitchen/product/portland-lg34-4p-1-handle-kitchen-faucet?modelNumber=LG34-4PS0), a model whose aerator thread is the non-standard 19mm male thread.

[image]

After reaching out to Doulton, they told me they sell an adapter for "overseas faucets" and non-standard sizes (the "ACC-FAU" accessory listed [here](http://doultonusa.com/HTML%20pages/doulton_filter_parts.htm)). It is a rubber adapter for faucets without a thread, that looks like this. I'm not happy with this solution since it might damage or leak and doesn't look very good (see [here](http://www.filterwater.com/pc-342-27-external-diverter-adapter.aspx), better picture).

I reached out to Pfister who simply said they do not make any accessories or parts for their faucets.

Not being extremely comfortable with the imperial system and with plumbing in general, I am at loss for solutions.

### **What adapter do I need to connect the male 19mm to the female 22mm/Standard elements?**

Ideally something made of non-rust material, that I can screw on between the two elements and easily remove when I move.